# How to search Spotify playlists by song?

Tags: spotify

In Spotify you can only search for public playlists by playlist title. This is unhelpful for obvious reasons. To demonstrate, a few of my public playlist names: *Tiny Danza*, *Peach World*, *Works*, *Jon Secada*. The Jon Secada playlist only has a single Jon Secada song in it. Anyone searching for Jon Secada playlists will probably be disappointed if he/she finds mine.

Is there any way to search playlists by the song/s that a playlist actually contains?

Comment: Another way is to search for the playlist by the song or artist name at http://playlists.net. This site is well integrated with spotify application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is a website that can help with finding Spotify playlists that contain a specific song or artists (or multiple of them)
Check it here https://www.chosic.com/spotify-playlist-search-tool-by-song-or-artist/

Answer (score 10):

Not officially. [This is an oft requested feature.](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Search-for-Public-Playlists-that-Contain-Song-Artist/idi-p/144576) (Vote it up so it gets attention.) And it's a feature that Rdio already provides.

But there is a "hack" that works, sort of.

Spotify community member [therepeatd](http://community.spotify.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/454754) [says](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Search-for-Public-Playlists-that-Contain-Song-Artist/idc-p/935409#M59828) Google this:

> site:spotify.com inurl:"playlist" "[artist name]" "[song name]"

... filling in the bracketed variables. Warning: Google may block your searches with a captcha because it thinks you're a robot. Also, while this method returns some public playlists that include a given song, it does not include all of them (many haven't been indexed).

This method will have to do until Spotify implements this feature or a third-party app figures out how to handle this on its own. [That may be a while](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Search-for-Public-Playlists-that-Contain-Song-Artist/idc-p/872323#M55166).

Comment: This works perfectly. Seems Spotify also formats their playlists with `[artist] · [song]` - using the format `site:spotify.com inurl:"playlist" "[artist] · [song]"` has worked nicely for me.

Comment: You can also search for playlists with two or more songs, just add other terms between quotes.

Comment: Any update on this?  As of 2018?

Answer (score 1):

shameless self promo incoming

I built a tool that let's you do this! https://whattheplaylist.com/

Music Lover's website above only seems to let you search public playlists. what the playlist lets you search your created and followed playlists for a song/album/artist

Answer (score 1):

I believe [playlistsearchr.com](https://playlistsearchr.com) allows you to do this. You can also search across apple music, amazon, youtube aswell as Spotify.

You can search playlists by the song/artist/album and easily preview them before adding them to your Spotify.